# Is there a way to add or extend web services in Dynamics CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

Is there a way to add or extend web services in Dynamics CRM 2013? We have an on-premise installation of Dynamics CRM 2013 that third party software need to be integrated with. We don't want to expose built-in web service operations to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamics CRM 2013 are exposed for all the users can reach the URL and have the privileges to operate (for example if the user has only the privilege to create accounts he can't create contacts).

You can create a proxy web-service if you want to control the access in different way.

Comment: +1 for suggesting the proxy web-service. A WCF web service in ASP.NET is how I usually solve this requirement. It can run on the same IIS server as CRM, assuming the load isn't an issue.